# How to read a collection property with JPA?

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I have two classes, `Account` and `Admin`, with many to many mapping.
The `Admin` class has a collection of `Account` class and vise versa.

I want to write a query, that given the account id, will return all the account admins.

Here is the relevant fields of the `Account` class:

```
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Admin> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I have tried a regular query for `Admin.class` with `multiselect` as each account has a collection of admins, but trying to get a `TypedQuery<Admin>` out of my `CriteriaQuery<Admin>` I got an `IllegalArgumentException` with the message "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [models.Admin]. Expected arguments are: java.util.Collection [select new models.Admin(generatedAlias0.users) from models.Account as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.id=1L]" (1L here probably since I called this function with 1 as accountId), caused by `QuerySyntaxException` with the message "Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [models.Admin]. Expected arguments are: java.util.Collection".

Code:

```
private static List<Admin> readAccountAdmins(Long accountId) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Admin> cq = cb.createQuery(Admin.class);
    Root<Account> root = cq.from(Account.class);

    Predicate idPredicate = cb.equal(root.get(Account_.id), accountId);
    cq.multiselect(root.get(Account_.users)).where(idPredicate);

    TypedQuery<Admin> typedQuery = JPA.em().createQuery(cq); // exception thrown here
    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

After that I tried running a `TypedQuery<List<Admin>>`, as I am trying to read a list. This is the first iteration of trying a query of list:

```
private static List<Admin> readAccountAdmins(Long accountId) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<List<Admin>> cq = cb.createQuery((Class<List<Admin>>)(Class<?>)(Collection.class));
    Root<Account> root = cq.from(Account.class);

    Predicate idPredicate = cb.equal(root.get(Account_.id), accountId);
    cq.select(root.get(Account_.users)).where(idPredicate);

    TypedQuery<List<Admin>> typedQuery = JPA.em().createQuery(cq);
    return typedQuery.getSingleResult(); // exception thrown here
}
```

I used `getSingleResult` as `getResultList` caused a compilation error, saying the actual return value is `List<List<Admin>>>` and doesn't match the signature.

This method threw a different exception, a `NonUniqueResultException` with the message: "result returns more than one elements".

While debugging, I tried to evaluate the expression `typedQuery.getResultList()` and saw that it actually returns `List<Admin>` and not `List<List<Admin>>`, so I got to my final iteration of this function:

```
private static List<Admin> readAccountAdmins(Long accountId) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<List<Admin>> cq = cb.createQuery((Class<List<Admin>>)(Class<?>)(Collection.class));
    Root<Account> root = cq.from(Account.class);

    Predicate idPredicate = cb.equal(root.get(Account_.id), accountId);
    cq.select(root.get(Account_.users)).where(idPredicate);

    TypedQuery<List<Admin>> typedQuery = JPA.em().createQuery(cq);
    return (List) typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Now, this function works, but my question is why?
Why did the compiler decide that `getResultList` returns a different value than the actual return value?

Comment: I ended up using a function similar to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135612/jpa-criteria-for-many-to-many-relationship, without any casting.

Would still like to know why I needed the casting in my original working function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it makes sense when you take a closer look at your database. A `TypeQuery` returns entities, so basically rows from tables. `List<Admin>` is a collection of Entities, so eventhough your `Account` has a `List<Admin>` as a field, the Query will still return `List<Admin>` entities, not `List<List<Admin>>` as `List<Admin>` is not an entity.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It does. I guess it will take some time for me to get it completely but each time I read your answer it makes more sense. Thanks!