# How to select fetched List<SomeEntity> in criteria api?

Tags: java, jpql, criteria-api

I have 2 entities with the `LAZY` `@ManyToMany` relationship, which are mapped through `guest_2_maintenance table`: `[order_id],[guest_id],[maintenance_id],[order_timestamp]`

```
@Entity
public class Guest {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "guests")
    private List<Maintenance> orderedMaintenances = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Maintenance {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "guest_2_maintenance",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "maintenance_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "guest_id"))
    private List<Guest> guests = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And I need to select `List<Maintenance> of the guest` through criteria. I may fetch the whole object and retrieve the `List<Maintenance>` through getter:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Guest> cq = cb.createQuery(Guest.class);
    Root<Guest> root = cq.from(Guest.class);
    root.fetch("orderedMaintenances", JoinType.INNER);
    TypedQuery<Guest> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq
            .select(root)
            .where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), guestId))
            .distinct(true));
    Guest guest = query.getSingleResult();
    List<Maintenance> resultList = guest.getOrderedMaintenances();
```

But I want to have the ability for different sortings, so using sql instead of comparator for that is preferable, could you advise, how to select **directly** `List<Maintenance>` from `query.getResultList()`?

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135612/jpa-criteria-for-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jpa criteria for many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135612/jpa-criteria-for-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: @Pp88 partly. There is the solution how to get the List<> with Join, meanwhile I was wondering about root.fetch possibilities to do that